# Specify the application root in web.config handler mapping

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httphandler

I have an application with an HttpHandler that processes any requests for a .js file. I only want this handler to process *.js files that are requested in the root of the application.

The handler mapping looks like this:

```
<add name="HandleJS" path="*.js" verb="*" type="MyApp.JsHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Currently, this handler processes ALL requested *.js files. Here is an example of the behavior I want.

This request would be processed by the handler:
http://localhost/myapps/approot/script.js

and this one would **not** be processed by the handler:
http://localhost/myapps/approot/dontProcessMe/script.js

I'd really like to avoid including the full absolute path in the handler path so I tried some other things first.

It doesn't look like the `path` property of the `add` element allows the use of the `~/` application root mechanism, so setting `path="~/*.js"` doesn't work.

I've also tried replicating the StaticFile handler that's built into IIS and doing something like this:

```
<add name="MyStaticFiles" path="*/*.js" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" />
```

or

```
<add name="MyStaticFiles" path="dontProcessMe/*.js" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" />
```

Both of which just return a blank response with an HTTP status of 200.

Help me Obi Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be inspect the RequestURL in the handler itself return the actual file if there is no processing needed?

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var applicationPath = context.Request.ApplicationPath;
    var pathAndQuery = context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

    var appRelativePath = pathAndQuery.Replace(applicationPath, "");

    var basePath = VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(appRelativePath);

    if (basePath != "/")
    {
        // load and return actual file
    }
    else
    {
        // custom logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I did almost exactly this earlier to work around the issue temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

No dice on `path="/*.js"` ?

It should be working with relative paths by default...

Comment: Nope. That would cause it to process from the server root [http://localhost/*.js](http://localhost/*.js), not the app root [http://localhost/myapps/approot/*.js](http://localhost/myapps/approot/*.js)